# How to understand this code of finding the longest word

Tags: ruby

I'm currently studying "Ruby language" and I get stuck at "`enumerable`" I tired hard to understand it, but still, here is an example.

```
my_array = %w{this is a test of the longest word check} 
longest_word = ''

my_array.each do |word|
  longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length
end

puts longest_word
#=> longest
```

I could understand almost every single line except  `longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length` i guess this is also the main part of this program, How could it get the wanted result by doing a comparison  like this?

At first i thought `longest_word`  is a default method, but it's obvious  not true. And then i refer it to "enumerable" Does it mean when each iterator iterating the words starting from the shortest until  the longest , Is that how we get the wanted result, Hope someone can help me to understand this more deeply and clearly.

Comment: Hint: for an array of numbers, how to find the max? It's basically the same.

Comment: @Snailwalker, Please only use English on SO, thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I will keep that in mind .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length` is a shorthand way of writing:

```
if longest_word.length < word.length
    longest_word = word
end
```

Here is an annotated version of the code:

```
# Define an array of words to test
my_array = %w{this is a test of the longest word check}

# Set our initial longest word to be a blank string so that any word will be longer than this 
longest_word = ''

# loop through the array testing each word in the order it was put into the array
my_array.each do |word|
  # if this word is longer than the longest word we have found so far, store it as the longest word
  longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length
end

# output the longest word
puts longest_word
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response  , but how could the program get the longest_word result by doing comparison  "longest_word.length < word.length " Can you make it more specific ?

Comment: @Snailwalker just added more to the answer, does it help?

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you again, But there is something still confusing. I did an experiment in IRB " word = %w{this is an experimentingaaaa} " puts word.length returns  4 , but experimentingaaaa length  is 16 way lager than 4 . In that case how can the longest_word.length returns  the result  "experimentingaaaa" which is smaller than 4 if "longest_word.length < 4

Comment: @Snailwalker I'm not exactly clear what you are asking, but it looks like you are creating an array `word = %w{this is an experimentingaaaa}` so when you say `word.length` it is returning the length of the array (4). You need to loop over the array using the `each` method to test the length of each item in the array.

Comment: Hi,i'm sorry for the confusion , For this example://///  my_array.each do |word|
  longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length ////  In other words, what is the value for word.length , is it a constant ?  Thank you.

Comment: @Snailwalker `longest_word = word if longest_word.length < word.length` gets called once for each string in your array with `word` being set to each string in the array successively. `word.length` gets the length of the string currently being processed

Comment: Thank you very much for this conversation, it's been very helpful  and I think i have asked enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, If you want to find longest word then You can try [**sort_by**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) too..

```
2.1.5 :001 >   my_array = %w{this is a test of the longest word check} 
 => ["this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "longest", "word", "check"]
2.1.5 :002 > my_array.sort_by(&:length).last
 => "longest"  # will return longest word from the string array
```

Why `.last` method?

```
2.1.5 :003 > my_array.sort_by(&:length)
 => ["a", "of", "is", "the", "this", "test", "word", "check", "longest"]
```

will sorting the array in ascending order as we want **longest word** so it is located at last `index`.

**Update:**
as [@engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682982/how-to-understand-this-code-of-finding-the-longest-word/27683751?noredirect=1#comment43797678_27683751) commented you can also use even more shorter method: [max_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by) too. Let's see how it's works:

```
 >  my_array = %w{this is a test of the longest word check} 
 => ["this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "longest", "word", "check"] 
 > my_array.max_by(&:length)
 => "longest"
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative method. :)

Comment: You could also use `max_by(&:length)` which will preform the same operation.

Comment: :) this one is reliable !

Comment: @engineersmnky : yes `max_by(&:length)` also can be used.. Thanks for another short method ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are few more alternates to get largest word -

```
2.1.5 :001 > my_array = %w{this is a test of the longest largest word check}
=> ["this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "longest", "largest", "word", "check"]
2.1.5 :001 > my_array.max {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length }
=> "longest"
```

or

```
2.1.5 :001 > my_array.max_by {|x| x.length }
=> "longest"
```